# react-native-image-crop-picker is Compressing the image before cropping

Tags: react-native

I have implemented this library. But on android only the image is being compressed when picking the image. For example, If I select like a large image `9921x4961` exactly and then log its width and height after being picked it will be `1241x621` which divided by 8 exactly. And this issue only appears on android.

Here is my implementation:

```
const res = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
   multiple: true,
   mediaType: 'any',
   compressVideoPreset: 'HighestQuality',
   maxFiles: 10
})
for await (const image of res) {
   Image.getSize(image.path, async (width, height) => {
     console.log('SIZE-PICKER: ', { width, height });
     await cropAndAttachImage(image);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `compressImageQuality: 1` in options.

If it still does not help, solution is to set a greater height/width manually.

```
const res = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
   width: 2048, // or something else depending on your use case
   height: 1024, // same as above
   compressImageQuality: 1,
   ....
})
```

You can also set width / height [x times viewport](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1356#issuecomment-958619208).

Similar issues [#1356](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1356), [#1085](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1085)